# App crashes when switching input source using caps lock in macOS Sierra

Tags: xcode, macos, swift3, macos-sierra

macOS Sierra has a new feature to switch input sources (keyboard layouts) using the caps lock key. (See screenshot)

[image]

**When this option is active, my app crashes on pressing Caps Lock.**

I don't get any meaningful stack trace besides `main`. Only `Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9` is reported. Apparently this is a memory violation.

This does not happen in other apps. But when switching the input source I get the following errors in console:

```
KIM_Extension   Current input mode is nil
```

I tried removing and re-adding the input sources but this did not have an effect.

Also, I must note that this **issue only appeared after I converted my app to Swift 3**.

Does anybody have deeper knowledge on how the caps lock events are handled? Is there a way to error check the event before it is sent to the app/system?

**Update:**
I think it is important to mention that switching input sources from the menu bar or using a regular keyboard shortcut works fine. So the problem is specific to the Caps Lock switching.